# Use triple integrals to find the volume of...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

The solid enclosed by the parabaloid $$x=y^2+z^2$$ and the plane $$x=6$$
I wanted to make sure that I'm setting up the correct integral before I start to integrate it. $$\int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\int_{-\sqrt{6-y^2}}^{\sqrt{6-y^2}}\int_{y^2+z^2}^6dxdydz$$
If this is incorrect, would someone be able to help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks ok. What makes you think you have a problem?

Comment: I'm just wanting to make sure it's correct before I start integrating and finding out that I did it all wrong :P

Comment: You'll have a much easier time if you notice that this is the same thing as the volume between $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=6$ and then use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: This is before we learned about cylindrical coordinates, so I'm not allowed to use them yet unfortunately :/

Comment: On thing caught my. You wrote $dx\,dy\,dz$. Presumably the first integration is w.r.t. $x$. There the limits are ok. But if you inted to do the $y$-integration next (as indicated in a way by the order of the differentials), then the limits can no longer depend on $y$. They may (and here also should) depend on the remaining variable $z$. So if you intended to do the $z$-integration before $y$-integration, then your limits are fine.

Comment: I find that it is often useful to denote the variable associated with each pair of limits under the integral sign. So I would write your integral as
$$\int_{y=-\sqrt6}^{\sqrt6}\int_{z=-\sqrt{6-y^2}}^{\sqrt{6-y^2}}\int_{x={y^2+z^2}}^6dx\,dz\,dy.$$
This is obviously not necessary, but I find it a useful memory aid. Looks a bit ugly also. But it is easy then also easy to check that the limits of an "inner" integral may depend on the "outer" integration variables, but on other variables. Which is the way it should be.

Comment: Sorry, late night editing dropped some key words from the two comments above. Hopefully you could still get my point :-)

Answer (score 2):

In any case, you can always validate your result by using the formula for a [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution), which in your case gives:

$$V = \pi \int f(x)^2 dx = \pi \int_0^6 \sqrt{x}^2 dx = 18\pi$$

Comment: Touche my friend :P

Comment: @JcE  Indeed, once you _do_ get to cylindrical coordinates, you'll recognize immediately that the integral you've written is equivalent to the "cylindrical shell" method for the volume...

Comment: Okay, sweet! Thanks for the help. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to make sure that I'm setting up the correct integral before I start to integrate it. 
>   $$\int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\int_{-\sqrt{6-y^2}}^{\sqrt{6-y^2}}\int_{y^2+z^2}^6dxdydz$$

The integration looks almost correct, except, the order of the integrated variable should be

$$\int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\int_{-\sqrt{6-y^2}}^{\sqrt{6-y^2}}\int_{y^2+z^2}^6 dx \color{red}{dz dy},$$
or 
$$\int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\int_{\color{red}{-\sqrt{6-z^2}}}^{\color{red}{\sqrt{6-z^2}}}\int_{y^2+z^2}^6dxdydz.$$

> This is before we learned about cylindrical coordinates, so I'm not allowed to use them yet unfortunately.

Of course the integral can be computed w/o any help from any spherization of the coordinate system. 
$$
V = \int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\int_{-\sqrt{6-z^2}}^{\sqrt{6-z^2}} (6-y^2-z^2) dydz
\\
= \int_{-\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{6}}\frac{4}{3}(6-z^2)\sqrt{6-z^2}dz
\\
= \frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{6}}(6-z^2)\sqrt{6-z^2}dz,
$$
which will yields the same answer with nbubis's answer if you use the trigonometric substitution you learned from Cal II: let $z = 6\sin \theta$ for $0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2$.